# Syntax for select wordpress core control type

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm modifying the WordPress Customizer by adding a dropdown list (select box) where users could choose from a few presets. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the syntax for it. Any seasoned veterans able to lend a hand? My current code is as follows:

```
    $wp_customize->add_control( /* Autum Brown */
        new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'top_nav_preset_autumn_brown',
            array(
                'label'    => __( 'Top Navigation Autum Brown', 'lws_setting'),
                'section'  => 'colors',
                'type'     => 'select',
                'settings' => 'header_links_menu_presets',
            )
    ) );
```

I would like to have at least 4 presets, namely: "Autumn Brown, Spring Green, Summer Fire, and Winter Blues".

I'm linking each preset to its own css file, like so:

```
function lws_customizer_css() {
    ?>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            <?php
                switch (get_theme_mod( 'header_links_menu_presets' )) {
                    case label1:
                        // Top Navigation Preset 1 - Spring Green
                        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/lws-customizer/top_nav_spring_green.css');       
                        echo "Label 1";
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Top Navigation Preset 1 - Spring Green
                        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/lws-customizer/top_nav_spring_green.css');       
                } 
            ?>
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'lws_customizer_css' );
```

It works perfectly fine when using a color picker, or text box but I can't figure this one out. Note, the switch case isn't working yet either, I'd like to fight with that one on my own before asking for help, just need help with the:
    'type' => 'select'

part...

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found the perfect tutorial to solve this problem: http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/